# How to set value in Vuex/Nuxt

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I am new to Vuex and Nuxt.

I would like to use vuex to fetch dropbox filestructure and store them.

Here is my code. the console.log seems to work fine. it prints out something like below.

But the structure still turns out to be [] when i use in index.vue

```
[ { '.tag': 'file',
    name: 'Document.docx',
    path_lower: '/posts/document.docx',
    path_display: '/posts/Document.docx',
    id: 'id:H_6Dhj1r7cEAAAAAAAAXlQ',
    client_modified: '2018-09-02T14:23:05Z',
    server_modified: '2018-09-02T14:23:06Z',
    rev: '5e5cab150',
    size: 11366,
    content_hash: 'd26bb0382752820694d31f42e82e31ef72bed683b90e02952ea09125264d4124' },
  { '.tag': 'file',
    name: '2013-5-17-first-post.md',
    path_lower: '/posts/2013-5-17-first-post.md',
    path_display: '/posts/2013-5-17-first-post.md',
    id: 'id:H_6Dhj1r7cEAAAAAAAAXlg',
    client_modified: '2018-09-02T14:25:38Z',
    server_modified: '2018-09-02T14:25:38Z',
    rev: '6e5cab150',
    size: 136,
    content_hash: '3b8d60de425e8280d55e45d7359cd3290abc5bc3b0bb6831b09a6da0d3cb6a12' } ]
```

the code is like below

```
import "isomorphic-fetch"
import {
  Dropbox
} from "dropbox";
import {
  DropboxTeam
} from "dropbox";
export const state = () => ({
  structure: []
});
export const mutations = {
  setStucture(state, structure) {
    state.structure = structure.slice();
    console.log(state.structure);
    // console.log(structure.slice());
  }
};
export const actions = {
  async nuxtServerInit({ commit }) {
    let accessToken = "XXXXX"
    let dropbox = new Dropbox({
      accessToken: accessToken
    });
    dropbox.filesListFolder({path: '/posts'})
    .then(response => {
      const structure = response.entries;
      commit("setStucture", structure);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
};
```

Can I get some help. Thank you!

Comment: I just solved my question. Seems like I forget to add await.

Answer (score 1):

add `await` to `dropbox.filesListFolder({path: '/posts'})` like below turned out to be the right answer.

```
await dropbox.filesListFolder({path: '/posts'})
```